# R - Apply custom function to column in data frame grouped by another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
df <-
    Time Value
    1    1    
    1    0.25    
    1    1    
    1    0.5    
    2    2    
    2    2    
    3    2    
    3    2
```

I want to group by Time and apply the following formula to Value.

```
# different probabilities
probs <- c(0.75, 0.99)
# accounts for probabilites <1
sel <- as.logical(probs < 1)

# function
cutPoints[1, sel] <- 10^qnorm(probs[sel], mean(df$Value), sd(df$Value))
```

When I run this I only get one Time value for each probability. It does not separate by Time. I need it to look like this:

```
Time    0.75    0.99
1       output  output  
2       output  output  
3       output  output
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `aggregate(Value~Time, df, \(x) 10^qnorm(setNames(probs, probs), mean(x), sd(x)))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This results in only one result for each of the probabilities. There should be results for each time point.